# How CLR converts Double/Single to Decimal internally?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I was interested to see how .NET converts `Double/Single` data types to `Decimal`, so I started Studying Decimal type struct source code that I came across to the code below.

It seems All other types conversions are implemented within framework's class library except `double/float` which are handled externally by CLR.

So, basically the question is **How CLR does the Conversion?**

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    public extern Decimal(float value);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    public extern Decimal(double value);

    public Decimal(int value)
    {
        int num = value;
        if (num < 0)
        {
            this.flags = -2147483648;
            num = -num;
        }
        else
        {
            this.flags = 0;
        }
        this.lo = num;
        this.mid = 0;
        this.hi = 0;
    }

    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public Decimal(uint value)
    {
        this.flags = 0;
        this.lo = (int)value;
        this.mid = 0;
        this.hi = 0;
    }

    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: How it's implemented in .NET Framework is a big guess without source code...but you can check how it's implemented in Mono: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Decimal.cs

Comment: It probably decomposes the floating point number, and try map it to the closest decimal

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti:   [DllImport("libdec", EntryPoint="double2decimal")]
  private static extern int double2decimal (out Decimal erg, double val, int digits);

Comment: @leppie, that's exactly what I'm interested, I wanted to know how they effectively convert a binary floating point to decimal floating point representation.

Comment: @user3473830: Unfortunately I cannot find the source for it...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, it seems currently Mono does it by converting it to string (Line 181), I doubt CLR implementation would do that.

Comment: @user3473830: Look at the #ifdef, it is not. Here is the native code: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/metadata/decimal.c#L942

Comment: @leppie you're right, it uses native implementation for double and string conversion for float https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Decimal.cs#L158

Comment: @leppie thanks, the link was very informative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is not as current as the latest CLR, the general details may be confirmed in the previously released SSCLI 2 (AKA [Rotor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Source_Common_Language_Infrastructure)). The native portions of System.Decimal are implemented in clr\src\vm\comdecimal.cpp. Each calls [VarDecFromR4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [VarDecFromR8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221241(v=vs.85).aspx), respectively. These are native APIs that are exposed by OleAut32.dll.

As for your next question: how does OleAut32 implement these functions? You're best bet is to attach a debugger and disassemble the functions. With WinDbg, you can do this with the [uf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558942(v=vs.85).aspx) command.

Comment: thanks, your information led me to check wine implementation http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/oleaut32/vartype.c